# QEMU doesn't support the virtualization of two CPUs

Tags: openstack, qemu, kvm, libvirt

My computer host machine has two phyiscal CPUs.The mode of mother board is WS C621E SAGE Manual.

```
root@ubuntu:~# lscpu
Architecture:            x86_64
  CPU op-mode(s):        32-bit, 64-bit
  Address sizes:         46 bits physical, 48 bits virtual
  Byte Order:            Little Endian
CPU(s):                  32
  On-line CPU(s) list:   0-31
Vendor ID:               GenuineIntel
  Model name:            Intel(R) Xeon(R) Silver 4208 CPU @ 2.10GHz
    CPU family:          6
    Model:               85
    Thread(s) per core:  2
    Core(s) per socket:  8
    Socket(s):           2
    Stepping:            7
    CPU max MHz:         3200.0000
    CPU min MHz:         800.0000
    BogoMIPS:            4200.00
    Flags:               fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology no
                         nstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid dca sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnow
                         prefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l3 cdp_l3 invpcid_single intel_ppin ssbd mba ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid cqm mpx rdt_
                         a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves cqm_llc cqm_occup_llc cqm_mbm_total cqm_mbm_local dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_act_window hwp
                         _epp hwp_pkg_req pku ospke avx512_vnni md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities
Virtualization features: 
  Virtualization:        VT-x
Caches (sum of all):     
  L1d:                   512 KiB (16 instances)
  L1i:                   512 KiB (16 instances)
  L2:                    16 MiB (16 instances)
  L3:                    22 MiB (2 instances)
NUMA:                    
  NUMA node(s):          2
  NUMA node0 CPU(s):     0-7,16-23
  NUMA node1 CPU(s):     8-15,24-31
Vulnerabilities:         
  Itlb multihit:         KVM: Mitigation: VMX disabled
  L1tf:                  Not affected
  Mds:                   Not affected
  Meltdown:              Not affected
  Mmio stale data:       Mitigation; Clear CPU buffers; SMT vulnerable
  Retbleed:              Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS
  Spec store bypass:     Mitigation; Speculative Store Bypass disabled via prctl and seccomp
  Spectre v1:            Mitigation; usercopy/swapgs barriers and __user pointer sanitization
  Spectre v2:            Mitigation; Enhanced IBRS, IBPB conditional, RSB filling, PBRSB-eIBRS SW sequence
  Srbds:                 Not affected
  Tsx async abort:       Mitigation; TSX disabled
```

When I use command:
root@ubuntu:~# egrep -c '(vmx|svm)' /proc/cpuinfo
64
but when I usec command:
root@ubuntu:~# virsh nodecpumap
CPUs present:   32
CPUs online:    32
CPU map:        yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy

So that means the QEMU hypervisor dosent supppor two phyiscal CPUs? How do I solve it ?

Openstack, KVM ,QEMU ,Libvirt

Answer (score 0):

The  lshw command has detected

- 2 sockets (physical CPUs)
- 8 cores per socket
- 2 threads per core

So the expected number of vcpus is 2 · 8 · 2 = 32.

If still in doubt, even the intel reference for [Xeon(R) Silver 4208](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/sku/193390/intel-xeon-silver-4208-processor-11m-cache-2-10-ghz/specifications.html) CPU states that you have 16 threads per CPU.